# Forecast Budget Tool On Power Apps

Tags: powerbi, powerapps

Can Power Apps be used to build a tool that allow for budgeting and forecasting? Along the lines of Data Entry via form? and how can you go about this

The goal is to allow a user to write back a Budget / Forecast value to a sql server table.

Month Budget Forecast
Jan20
Feb20
Mar20
Apr20
.. etc

In addition, it will need to be designed to allow users to enter both budget and forecast via inventory level such as by Panel Class, by Format etc.

Either way, MonthYear or Inventory levels, the total values need to roll up to be the same. Similar to cubes on Board reporting tool.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

In short, yes you can create form to submit data to the database and then analyze and display data in PowerBI. PowerApp and PowerBI can work together in many scenarios. Here you may have a quick idea of the possibilities..
https://www.predicagroup.com/blog/powerapps-and-power-bi/